# Why do I get undefined on pinia store table variable when trying to use it in the template?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have created a pinia store factory function that I have a table variable in and when I declare a store in a Vue component and try to use the table from that store I get undefined.

I tried using the onBeforeMount lifecycle hook inside of the factory function but it did not help.

This is the code with the factory function

```
import { StoreDefinition, defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core';
import type { Ref } from 'vue';
import type { RemovableRef } from '@vueuse/core';
import type { Table } from "@/types/generalTypes";
import { customDateFormatter } from '@/composables/useDateFormatter';

export type CustomStore = {
    table: RemovableRef<Table>;
    addToTable: (rowToAdd: Record<string, any>) => Table;
    removeFromTable: (indexToRemove: number) => Table;
    returnItemFromTable: (indexToReturn: number) => Record<string, string>;
    loading: Ref<boolean>;
};

export const createTableStore = (id: string): StoreDefinition<string, any> => {
    const storageKey = `table_${id}`;
    return defineStore(id, () => {
        const table: RemovableRef<Table> = useStorage(storageKey, { headers: [], data: [] });
        const loading = ref(false);

        function addToTable(rowToAdd: Record<string, any>): Table {
            loading.value = true;
            const tempTable: Record<string, any> = {};
            for (const key in rowToAdd) {
                if (rowToAdd[key] == null) return table.value;
                if (rowToAdd[key] instanceof Date) { 
                    tempTable[key] = customDateFormatter(rowToAdd[key]);
                    continue;
                }
                tempTable[key] = rowToAdd[key];
            }
        
            table.value.data.push(tempTable);
            setTimeout(() => loading.value = false, 1000);
            return table.value;
        }

        function removeFromTable(indexToRemove: number): Table {
            loading.value = true;
            table.value.data = table.value.data.filter((_, index) => index !== indexToRemove);
            setTimeout(() => loading.value = false, 1000);
            return table.value;
        }

        function returnItemFromTable(indexToReturn: number): Record<string, string> {
            const item = table.value.data.find((_, index) => index === indexToReturn);
            return item;
        }

        return { table, addToTable, removeFromTable, returnItemFromTable, loading } as CustomStore;
    });
}
```

And this is where I declare the store and try to pass table as a prop

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, inject } from 'vue';
import type { Ref } from 'vue';
import BaseForm from '@/components/BaseForm.vue';
import Table from '../Tables/Table.vue';
import FormFilePicker from '../FormComponents/FormFilePicker.vue';
import { createTableStore } from '@/stores/tableStore';
import type { CustomStore } from '@/stores/tableStore';

const projectData = inject('projectData');
const toUploadTableStore: unknown = createTableStore('to-upload-table');
const typedToUploadTableStore = toUploadTableStore as CustomStore;

const fromDatabaseStore: unknown = createTableStore('from-database-table');
const typedFromDatabaseStore = fromDatabaseStore as CustomStore;

function passToTable(files: { src: File }[]): void {
    const date = new Date();
    for (const file of files) {
        const fileName = file.src.name;
        const fileType = file.src.type;
        typedToUploadTableStore.addToTable({ fileType, date, fileName });
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div>
            <Table 
                :headers="[
                    { id: 0, description: 'Πολυμέσα' },
                    { id: 1, description: 'Ημ. Δημιουργίας' },
                    { id: 2, description: 'Αρχείο' }
                ]"
                :data="typedToUploadStore.table.value.data"
                :tableModifiers="{ canDeleteItem: true }"
                @delete-item="(index: number) => typedToUploadTableStore.removeFromTable(index)"
            />
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there might be a typo in your template. In the template section, you are trying to access **typedToUploadStore** instead of **typedToUploadTableStore**. This should resolve the issue of table being undefined in your component.